# how to find a power series solution for this differential equation , by substitute odd and even number

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

when I wanna solve this differential equation by power series

[image]

I reach here

[image]

how to solve this differential equation and get the power series solution, just by substituting odd and even numbers and find the pattern between them

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence relation should be:
$$a_{n+2}=-\dfrac {a_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)} \text { for } n \ge 1$$
$$a_2=0$$
The solution can't be expressed with elementary known functions. You will need [Airy's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) for the solution of the DE.